# how to unzip multiple volume zip files with apache ant?

Tags: java, ant, unzip

i have a single file that's over 100 Mb

- some-archive.bin

i've used 7z to create multiple volumes of this single file (using zip format). the resulting volumes look something like the following.

- some-archive.zip.001
- some-archive.zip.002

i need to use apache ant v1.9.3 to unzip all these volumes to recover the original file. i tried something like the following, which didn't work.

```
<unzip src="some-archive.zip.001" dest="output-dir"/>
```

is this something that is not supported out of the box by ant? meaning, will i have to write my own ant task to accomplish this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116443/how-do-you-uncompress-a-split-volume-zip-in-java see the answer and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823187/how-do-you-use-ant-to-unjar-multiple-jar-files-and-rebuild-them-into-one-jar-fil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you had zipped the *some-archive.bin* file and then split the *some-archive.zip* file into multiple volumes, you could use the [**concat**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task with ***binary*** set to true and a ***destfile*** specified in order to merge the volumes back into a single zip file. Then unzip the *some-archive.zip* with the **[unzip](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)** task.

```
<target name="merge-and-unzip">

  <concat destfile="some-archive.zip" binary="true">
    <fileset dir=".">
      <include name="some-archive.zip.*"/>
    </fileset>
  </concat>

  <unzip dest="." src="some-archive.zip"/>

</target>
```