# In Maven, how to iterate folder/directory?

Tags: maven

I have directory with 100 files under it. I just want to print it. Please find below the plugin I have written. I am getting following error:

[ERROR] PluginConfigurationException:
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run for parameter outputDirectory: Cannot find 'outputDirectory' in class org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:605)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
    at com.soebes.maven.plugins.iterator.ExecutorMojo.executeMojo(ExecutorMojo.java:302)

The code is as below:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>validate</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>iterator</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <folder>${user.home}/${dasmo.storage}</folder>
                  <pluginExecutors>
                    <pluginExecutor>
                      <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                      </plugin>
                      <goal>run</goal>
                      <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="base dir is ${item}" />
                        </tasks>
                      </configuration>
                    </pluginExecutor>
                  </pluginExecutors>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: Note: Depending on your OS, there are probably better ways to print the contents of a folder.

Comment: What is your intention for using iterator-maven-plugin?

Comment: Aaron Digulla and Khmarbaise, basically I have 100 zip file in my directory. I want to unzip each one of these files. I do not want to specify hardcoded value of zip file. So, that is the reason I am using iterator.

Comment: Are those zip files generated by a maven build? Create a maven-assembly-descriptor and you don't need to defined all zip files..

Comment: Khmarbaise, thanks. No, those 100s of zipped files are created by me. Its not created by Maven Build. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven uses `DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields()` to copy values from the POM into fields of the plugin. In your case, the manager has decided that the plugin `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run` (implemented by `org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo`) must know the value of `outputDirectory` and tries to set it.

I don't see a reason why `DefaultMavenPluginManager` thinks that the mojo (plugin) would need this property since it's not mentioned in the POM. My next step would be to start my debugger and step through the code to see where `DefaultMavenPluginManager` gets the list of properties to configure in a mojo. Maybe you can influence this or there is a configuration error elsewhere (like in the parent POM).

**[EDIT]** If you want to unzip many files at once, Maven is probably the wrong tool. Try `Ant` which can be configured to do the task with just a few lines in `build.xml`. See this question for a solution: [How do you use ant to unjar multiple JAR files and rebuild them into one JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823187/how-do-you-use-ant-to-unjar-multiple-jar-files-and-rebuild-them-into-one-jar-fil)

Alternatively, you can use PowerShell on Windows to do the job in a script or use this script on Linux:

```
for f in *.zip ; do
    unzip "$f"
done
```

Comment: Aaron, how do you unzip 100 zip files under directory c:\xyx\zippedfile\ please suggest me solution. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my question; in your case, Ant is probably the best solution unless you know PowerShell.

Comment: I will try. Can I mix ant and maven together?

Comment: Yes, by using the [Maven AntRun plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) directly. The documentation has examples how to use it.